# Do non-synchronized i++ overlap?

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic, context-switch

Attempting to get Java multithreading basics I've run into a case I can't understand. Community, please share your exp why this is happening:
I have a Runnable:

```
class ImproperStateWorker implements Runnable {
    private int val = 0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Where are missing ticks?
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    val++;
                    Thread.yield();
                    val++;
        }
        showDataState();
    }

    public void showDataState() {
        System.out.print(Thread.currentThread() + " ; ");
        System.out.println(val);
    }
}
```

which is started via:

```
public class ImproperState {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ImproperStateWorker worker = new ImproperStateWorker();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(worker);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

}

I understand that the idea is to make both increment operations atomic by using `synchronized() {...}`, and so on. 
But I am confused with the following: Why running these two Runnables (without sync) does not produce the consistent result of 4000 (1000 x 2 increments per task)? Regardless of how the context is switched between the two task, I expect that the tasks will perform 2000 increments each, I don't care what the order will be.

However, the program output gives ~3.5K.
The only idea I can think of is that "missing" increments emerge because some of them are made simultaneously so that `val++` called from two threads actually increases the value by 1. But this is a very vague assumption. Thanks for sharing your experience.

Comment: Executive answer: yes

Comment: To elaborate on that, `i++` consists of `read`, `increment`, `assign` steps. There's plenty of chance to overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a race condition in your code. Consider the following possible interleaving:

1. **Thread 1**: reads `val` → `0`
2. **Thread 1**: increments `0` → `1`
3. **Thread 1**: writes `val` ← `1`
4. **Thread 1**: reads `val` → `1`
5. **Thread 1**: increments `1` → `2`
6. **Thread 1**: writes `val` ← `2`
7. **Thread 2**: reads `val` → `2`
8. **Thread 2**: increments `2` → `3`
9. **Thread 2**: writes `val` ← `3`
10. **Thread 2**: reads `val` → `3`
11. **Thread 2**: increments `3` → `4`
12. **Thread 2**: writes `val` ← `4`
13. End State: `val == 4`

All is good. But, consider this equally possible interleaving:

1. **Thread 1**: reads `val` → `0`
2. **Thread 2**: reads `val` → `0`
3. **Thread 1**: increments `0` → `1`
4. **Thread 2**: increments `0` → `1`
5. **Thread 1**: writes `val` ← `1`
6. **Thread 2**: writes `val` ← `1`
7. **Thread 1**: reads `val` → `1`
8. **Thread 2**: reads `val` → `1`
9. **Thread 1**: increments `1` → `2`
10. **Thread 2**: increments `1` → `2`
11. **Thread 1**: writes `val` ← `2`
12. **Thread 2**: writes `val` ← `2`
13. End State: `val == 2`

Oops!

In the code as written in your question, the result can be *anything* between `2000` and `4000`.

One way to fix this is to use an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) with [`AtomicInteger.getAndIncrement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#getAndIncrement()) or [`AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet()) (in your case it doesn't matter which since you ignore the return value; the correct equivalent to postfix `val++` would be `val.getAndIncrement()`) instead, like this (you only need to change three places, not counting the `import`.):

```java
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

class FixedStateWorker implements Runnable {
    private AtomicInteger val = new AtomicInteger();
    //      ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑       ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            val.getAndIncrement();
            //  ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
            Thread.yield();
            val.getAndIncrement();
            //  ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
        }
        showDataState();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two interacting problems. One is the race condition already mentioned, and the other is the lack of visibility between threads of changes to a shared variable. You must use some concurrency idiom to resolve both of those situations.